# INSERT INTO - cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I encountered an error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() when using INSERT INTO:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'https:'.

Glad if someone can help.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class Form1
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
    
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
    
            While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
                Application.DoEvents()
            End While
    
            RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText
    
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO tTempList (ExtData) VALUES('" & RichTextBox1.Text & "')"), con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            con.Connectionstring = "Server=SURFACEPRO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PropApp;Integrated Security=True"
        End Sub
    
    End Class
```

Comment: i think RichTextBox1.Text have some invalid Charater by.which query can excute .please pick query while running into debugging mode.then execute that query into sql .check what is happening .i think you will get solution.

Comment: Thank for your prompt advise.  Will try and update.

Comment: Use parameters aswell @Toh. Well worth it in the end.

Answer (score 3):

**Use Sql parameters!**

If you will use parameters you will never face such a problems. In addition parameters will save you from possible Sql injection.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

    Using connection As New SqlConnection()
        connection.Open()
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tTempList (ExtData) VALUES (@ExtData)"
        Dim parameter As New SqlParameter With 
        { 
            .ParameterName = "@ExtData", 
            .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, 
            .Value = RichTextBox1.Text 
        }

        Usinig command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt advise and help.  will try and update the outcome..

Comment: Definitely use this example which Fabio was kind enough to draw up @Toh. Will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly and I managed to insert into the sql table.

Comment: Thank you Fabio.  One more help needed.  I am very new in sqlparameter.  how to code the second or third parameters if I have a few more fields to insert into sql table... say eg ExtDate (Date) and ExtRecno (integer)

Comment: Create a array of paramters you need and add the to the command by `command.Parameters.AddRange`. `command.Parameters` is collection so you can execute `Add` method as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got ' somewhere in you textbox. You should always use sqlparameters to avoid this kind of errors and sql injection

Comment: Thank for your prompt advise. will try and update the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

    Using connection As New SqlConnection()
        connection.Open()
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tTempList (ExtData,oCategory,oSubcategory) VALUES (@ExtData,@oCategory,@oSubcategory)"

        Using Command As New SqlCommand(query, con)

            Command.Parameters.Add("@ExtData", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Command.Parameters("@ExtData").Value = RichTextBox1.Text
            Command.Parameters.Add("@oCategory", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Command.Parameters("@oCategory").Value = CmbCategory.Text
            Command.Parameters.Add("@oSubcategory", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            Command.Parameters("@oSubcategory").Value = cmbSubcategory.Text

            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Thank you Fabio for your kindness to guide.
Thank you Zach and Jinx88909 for your advise too.